# NoMethodError: undefined method `to_h' for #<OrderGroup:0x0000000124e73f40> Did you mean? to_s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to convert data inside `OrderGroup1` to a hash using `to_h`, but it is throwing the following error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_h' for #<OrderGroup:0x0000000124e73f40> Did you mean? to_s
```

My current version is `ruby 2.7.6p219 (2022-04-12 revision c9c2245c0a) [arm64-darwin22]`.

The methods `to_s` and `to_h` are not working for me.

Is there a workable solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `to_h` on an ActiveRecord object but you can get the attributes hash by calling the `attributes` method

```
OrderGroup.find(1).attributes
```